# Esri API 10.2 - Error code: 400 "Unable to complete operation"

Tags: ios, arcgis, esri

I am developing an iOS Application for collecting data following "FeatureLayerEditingSample"(you can find it here: [FeatureLayerEditingSample](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=2ddb261648074b9aabb22240b6975918)).

I use Esri's iOS sdk version 10.2
This error occurs random sampling when I try to add a new feature (simple or with attachments) to my feature layer.

Moreover sometimes only one or two specific attachments cannot be sync and the error says "because unable to complete operation".
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was using a versioned database. Removing the version all worked again.

Answer (score 1):

When using REST API to add new feature, please make sure you do your request using **POST** and make sure you have included **f** and **features** parameters in the POST body.
Below is an example of the POST request in JavaScript(AngularJS) - it can be easily transferred to any other language:

```
$scope.addFeature= function(){

            var url = "http://services6.arcgis.com/dD0xfCNJ6qLYAvCQ/arcgis/rest/services/US_Election_2016/FeatureServer/0/addFeatures";

            var newFeature = {
            "geometry" : {"x" : -122.504002, "y" : 45.448060},  
            "attributes" : {
              "CandidateName" : "Hillary Clinton"
            },
            "spatialReference" : {
            "wkid" : "4326"
            }
            };

            var features = [];
            features.push(newFeature);

           var featuresString = JSON.stringify(features);

            data = "f=json&features="+featuresString;

            var config={
              headers : {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
            }};

           $http.post(url, data, config)
           .then(
               function(response){
                 console.log(response);
               }, 
               function(response){
                 console.log(response);
               }
            );
       }
```

Comment: idk why i use             data = "f=json&features="+featuresString;
 it works for me